# Output when using Pre-processors in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Here f(3+3) is replaced by f(6)= 6*6 ?
So the output should be 36 na? So why and how the answer is 15?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #define f(a) a*a
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
cout<<f(3+3);
}
```

Comment: Operator precedence and missing parentheses. The preprocessor just does simple text replacement. Think over the result.

Comment: Don't use macros in C++ - problem solved. `int f(int a) { return a*a; }` instead of your macro would _just work_.

Comment: @AlanStokes That's merely true for C, at least with this case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed. I almost put the `inline` in there, but it's such a simple example it's not needed.

Comment: **This is an example of why macros are evil.** I highly recommend you use inline functions instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro invocation

```
f(3 + 3)
```

is replaced by

```
3 + 3 * 3 + 3
```

This is the reason that arguments to macros usually is put between parentheses:

```
#define f(a) (a) * (a)
```

---

As a side-note, if you use a variable instead of a literal integer, and does something like

```
int a = 3;
int result = f(a++);
```

Then the macro is replaced by

```
(a++) * (a++)
```

leading to `a` being incremented *twice*. *And* in an unknown order, leading to *undefined behavior*.

In C++ there are seldom any use for function-like macros any more, and with all the problems with them (as shown above) you really should not use them. Use functions, they behave correctly, the compiler can still inline them, and they are type-safe (think about what would happen if you did e.g. `f("3")`, you might get weird errors that are hard to track down).

Comment: You forgot to bracket the result, too.`#define f(a) ((a) *(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Because 3 + 3 × 3 + 3 = 15.

Try using parentheses to achieve what you want.